# adding msgbox inside findstring loop Excel VBA

Tags: excel

I have a code as below. there are 2 workbooks I have used. one of them is taking the data from system and the other workbook is filled by users manually.
code is combining 2 columns on both workbooks and search for the data on 2nd workbook. if matchs, adding the data, which is in 1st workbook, to workbook 2.
unless there is another column need to be added this code. but there is an issue, 3rd column on workbook 2 can have typo mistakes or shorten versions of the words.
so, user need to decide which cell need to be filled.
for example ;
[image: Workbook1]
[image: Workbook2]
so below macro directly find and adding the data to 1st and 4th rows. but I know the data need to be added on only 4th row because user can understand tt means on 2nd workbook column 3 is Turk Telekom. so I need a msgbox addition to ask user column 3 is xx do you want to add, and also ask on 4th row column 3 is tt do you want to add.

```
findstring1 = wb.Sheets("Sheetname").Range("E4").Value
    findstring2 = wb.Sheets("sheetname").Range("E5").Value
    
    firstrow = 2
    lastcell = s.Cells(2, 1).End(xlDown).Row
    
        For i = firstrow To lastcell
        
        If Left(s.Cells(i, 3), 3) = findstring1 And s.Cells(i, 4) = findstring2 Then
            If s.Cells(i, 21) = "" Then
                s.Cells(i, 21) = wb.Sheets("sheetname").Range("I4")
             Else
                s.Cells(i, 22) = s.Cells(i, 22).Value & " done on " & wb.Sheets("sheetname").Range("I4") & "."
            End If
        End If
            
        Next i
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
firstrow = 2
    lastcell = s.Cells(2, 1).End(xlDown).Row
    
        For i = firstrow To lastcell
        
        If Left(s.Cells(i, 3), 3) = findstring1 And s.Cells(i, 4) = findstring2 Then
         Dim myReply     As Integer
    myReply = MsgBox("Matched code is as below. Would you like to Continue? [YES] Or Not [NO] ?" & " " & s.Cells(i, 6), _
              vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "code Check")
    Select Case myReply
        Case Is = vbYes
    Application.Cursor = xlWait
            If s.Cells(i, 21) = "" Then
                s.Cells(i, 21) = wb.Sheets("sheetname").Range("I4")
             Else
                s.Cells(i, 22) = s.Cells(i, 22).Value & " bla bla bla " & wb.Sheets("sheetname").Range("I4") & "."
            End If
        
        Case Is = vbNo
        End Select
        End If
        Next i
```

worked for me